# How can i increase the height of the UIView automatically if the number of children increases in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a dynamic `storyboard` in which there is a `UIView` inside which, i have to add multiple (count is variable) items. So the height of the view is variable, i am unable to find the solution, as I am new to iOS.

In android I know how to do this by using height as wrap content.

[image]

Comment: You can use scrollview for this

Comment: this story board already contains a scrollview and inside that srollview i have many uiviews just like i explained above.

Comment: if you have the constraints set to the uiview, then you can change the height constraint to increase the view height

Comment: @Mr.T can you u please explain how to do that, actually i have idea that this can be solved by adding some constraint, but i don't understand by looking into the guides, how to add constraint.

Comment: post the  screenhot of view heirarchy in ur storyboard

Comment: just set the view height programatically by calculating last view Y-asis+height if you are not flexible with constraints

Comment: @ismail i already tried this, somehow i am able to change the width but unable to increase heinght, i used below code.

    CGRect newFrame = _recentOrderContainer.frame;
    //newFrame.size.width = 20;
    newFrame.size.height = 6500;
    [_recentOrderContainer setFrame:newFrame];

Comment: Looking at your picture, I'd say you should be using a table view.

Comment: do you used constraints?if yes then the screenshot with constraints

Comment: i dont understand how to add height constraint, thanks in advance.

Comment: @RatneshKumar newFrame.size.height = 6500; by doing this you are restricting the height to assign dynamically you should use newFrame.size.height=lastview.frame.origin.y+lastview.frame.size.height; there are only two ways you can do this 1 by above code or by adding constraint please show some code to understand the problem better.

Comment: @ismail if i run the above mentioned code the _recentOrderContainer is the area coloured blue, it remains the same size but the content inside it shrunk or expand accordingly.

i used this code after knowing the required height of this container after adding children inside this blue area.

Comment: @RatneshKumar please show some code or the view structure

Comment: @ismail I am just testing how to add height constraint on uiview to expand automatically when its children increases.

Comment: can someone help me, i am still stuck in here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use AutoLayout it should be easy to you. In other case you should calculate every layer x and y, width and height position in order to build.

Comment: i already followed this approach, calculated x and y, width and height and then tried to increase height of the view, still unable to accomplish that.